# Is there some way of guranteeing object permanence in memcached?

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

I am using memcached to store the global state of a php website. The data stored needs to be accessed by requests from any logged in user.

I am aware that if memcached gets full it will just dump the oldest objects. Is there some fallback technique that can be used in this case?

Alternatively, disregard memcached. What is a faster way of storing global state in Php without resorting to MySQL?

Comment: Curious what your reluctance to use MySQL is?

Comment: Just trying to speed things up. All I'm storing is a tuple {'userid', 'state1', 'state2', 'state3} per user sorted in 9 arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store as JSON in the session. You can also use Redis (instead of memcached) with PHP and set max memory use.

Comment: Redis seems like a good option, thanks. Regarding sessions, aren't they per user, i.e. not global?

Comment: Yes, sessions are per user. For global stuff, use Redis.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is like to ask that how is to keep something in memory for a long time.

Memcache drop the old item if it is full and you add another item into it. your application should work in a way that the procedure of putting some items in the cache should activated when the cache return null or is disabled by any reason. 
soemthing like this: 
1- read the Item from cache 
2- if the Item is not null 
3- return the Item 
4- read the Item from database(or any other source)
5- put the Item in cache 
6- return the Item

Cache is not a permanent memory and your application should be design in a way that can work even without the cash.

However because it is the application state probably the call to that item is so high that will not go to the end of the queue. 
Although this is not a good approach but you can also create a service to get that item from cache to prevent it to go to the end of queue.